70s Lovecraftian novel where someone's lower jaw is torn off
Some time in the 1970s I read a Lovecraftian novel that I think involved an expedition underground - along the lines of Verne's Journey to the Centre of the Earth but much trashier. The protagonists run into some sort of Lovecraftian deity that slaughters them in innovative ways, and at the end only the main protagonist escapes but is driven to near madness (again a Lovecraftian cliché).
The only scene I remember clearly is where the main protagonist encounters the body of an expedition member and the big bad has torn off the unfortunate person's lower jaw and replaced it with some form of Lovecraftian body horror - probably a tentacle of some kind. The scene must have made quite an impression of me for me to remember it fifty years later.
I could have sworn the author was Clark Ashton Smith, but I've been through all his works several times without finding it so it must be another of the many writers inspired by Lovecraft (if "inspired" is the right word!). I'm sure it was by a reasonably well known author who had written several other similar books, and not an unknown author who was never heard from again, but there were a lot of people writing this sort of stuff in the 60s and 70s.
I very much doubt the novel is a great work of literature, but it's something I've been wondering about for a long time and it would be interesting to see just how bad my teenage taste in books was.
I've added the Cthulhu Mythos tag because I remember it that way, but I'm not sure if it featured deities invented by Lovecraft or just similar rip-offs.

Possibly Basil Cooper's The Great White Space (1974) about an expedition to a lost city beneath the ground. Here's a description via the re-print: https://www.valancourtbooks.com/the-great-white-space-1974.html

That ... could be it! My goodness, I think you might have found it! I'll have to find a copy of the novel to see. And it explains why I suddenly thought of the book - it's because I've just id'd Copper's The Janissaries of Emiilion as the answer to a question and that may have triggered a memory.

@Cassfrank I haven't found the book yet, but I'm convinced you're correct. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. If/when I find the book I will edit the scene I remember into your answer.

This sounds so much like the Harlan Ellison story, "I Have No Mouth but I Must Scream".

As John Rennie mentioned in the comment section, this is most likely Basil Cooper's 1974 Lovecraftian novel/pastiche/homage The Great White Space.
Below is an overview of the book's plot:

Traveling to an undisclosed remote location in the far east, Scardale’s expedition crosses vast stretches of wasteland, meets isolated tribes, climbs the shunned Black Mountains, and finally enters a system of tunnels that have been burrowed deep into the mountainside.  These tunnels possess doorways five hundred feet high, designed for the passage of something more or less than human.  At the end of their journey, the researchers will find The Great White Space — but only one of them will survive to return and tell his story...
Copper’s descriptions of the underground tunnels and the city that lies within it are captivating and give an appropriate sense of awe and horror.  He really does it right, providing enough detail to paint a vivid picture but only giving hints at greater secrets, leaving the underworld a place of mystery and horror.
The culminating horror is well worth the wait, and the novel even ends
with a bit of a twist that is again very much in the line of
Lovecraft’s original work.

The scene with the jaw removal is:

Perhaps we had interrupted the bat creature at a crucial moment of the metamorphosis or possibly the process was a long elaborate one. I was prepared for anything but the ruined mask of Van Damm's dead features which confronted me. Poor Van Damm's lower jaw had been quite torn off in some disgusting manner, exposing the upper teeth and splintered bone of the jaw connections with long driblets of blackened blood hanging down from the ruin. More disgusting still, the skull had been opened in some ingenious manner - perhaps with a cutting tool on the bat creature's trunk — and the brainbox exposed.

